# Magento 2 : We need to save product two time After generating Custom Option programmatically?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, custom-options, catalog-product

I have work on Custom Module.
In Our Module I had use

```
<event name="catalog_product_save_after">
    <observer name="add_custom_option" instance="Namespace\Modulename\Observer\AddCustomOption" />
</event>
```

In observer i Had Generate Product Custom Option Programmatically

```
            $product->setHasOptions(1);
            $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
            foreach ($options as $arrayOption) {
                $isHasOptions = $product->getTypeInstance()->hasOptions($product);

                 $option = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                        ->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')
                        ->setProductId($product->getId())
                        ->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())
                        ->addData($arrayOption);

                $this->customoptionOperation($option, 'save');
                $product->addOption($option);
                //$product->save();
            }
```

i have use this code for generate Product custom Option.

> //$product->save();

i had comment this code because it provide me Error

> No Such Entity

After saving Product.

**Product Options are generated Successfully in Product But Not Display in Front-end**

I had Run All Commands

- setup:upgrade
- setup:static-content:deploy -f
- indexer:reindex
- cache:flush

But Custom Option Not Appears in Front-end

But When i have save product second time after saving product the Options are Appears in Front-end Without need Run any Commands.

> I Need Solution to save Product One time and Get Product Option Front End

Is This Possible ?

Comment: I have also the same problems

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a Product Repository `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductCustomOptionRepositoryInterface`

Like this:

```
$product->setHasOptions(1);
$product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
foreach ($options as $arrayOption) {
    $isHasOptions = $product->getTypeInstance()->hasOptions($product);

    $option = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductCustomOptionRepositoryInterface')
                ->setProductId($product->getId())
                ->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())
                ->addData($arrayOption);

    $this->customoptionOperation($option, 'save');
    $product->addOption($option);
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: it is not working and read My Question $product->save() provide me Error No Such Entity

Comment: updated it using `ProductCustomOptionRepositoryInterface` , using it, **save()** will work without error

Comment: No it is not working it will provide me Error [ https://www.screencast.com/t/Xp8XahLTV ]

Comment: which Magento version you are using?

Comment: i have use magento 2.3.1

Comment: can you add whole addcustomoption obeserver code

Answer (score 1):

**Save Product Using `ProductRepositoryInterface` :-**

```
$option = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::class)
        ->setProductId($_product->getId())
        ->setStoreId($_product->getStoreId())
        ->addData($arrayOption);
    $option->save();
    $product->addOption($option);
    $productRepo = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
    $productRepo->save($product);
```

Comment: try this.......

Comment: it will provide Me Error No such Entity [https://www.screencast.com/t/hZhbqSSinL]

Comment: Page Not Found in your screenshot

Comment: TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor::save() must implement interface Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface, instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option